# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel disappears only on edit pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

im following this tutorial : http://untame.net/2012/08/twitter-bootstrap-build-a-stunning-two-column-blog/

and my carousel works fine (scrolling works fine, all the images are rendered) but when i navigate to an `EDIT` page then is just disappears but still shows the scrolling function

here it is working : 
http://s7.postimage.org/dsf75yc6z/Carousel.png

and now i pressed `EDIT` : http://s13.postimage.org/64i1v0hif/Carousel2.png

this is the carousel code in my layout:

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
      <!-- Carousel items -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item"><img src="../slider/musteri.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="../slider/Deepak.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="../slider/4.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="../slider/1.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="../slider/2.jpg" /></div>
      </div>
      <!-- Carousel nav -->
      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div>
```

my `EDIT` function is scaffold made:

```
# GET /news/1/edit
def edit
  @news = News.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @news }
  end
end
```

My `EDIT` view simply renders `<%= render 'form' %>`

that form is the same as the one that is used for `NEW` and there the carousel works fine!

and that is making me nuts! Any ideas ? :D

Comment: no one experienced this before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is the path to your images. Rails has the asset pipeline so you don't really need to put the images within another folder within the asset folder. (hope that makes sense)

Take your images out of your slider folder and just place them in

```
assets/images
```

and then when you want to call an image just use

```
<img src="/assets/filename.jpg">
```

Hope that helps